# CSS Color the container

Tags: css, containers

I am new to this language so I want to know how I can color the container (the part between header and footer). Is it possible without using div? I have tried this, but problem is that when I change the position of the container to "absolute" it overlaps the header more over changes the page's width Please give an example code. Thanks.

Comment: what do you mean by container? what's a container in html?

Comment: The space between header and footer (The space for main body)

Comment: what's header and what's footer in html when you are not using div? there is no header footer tag. I believe you are talking about divs with class names header, footer and container. So you have to apply your style on that div. If your div class is called container, in css, you do #container {background : yourcolor; }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
html , body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background: red;
}
```

I made html and body 100% just in case. You probably don't need it. But I suggest that you never have a naked body as your background.

EDIT : Or if you want an image

```
body {
background:url('http://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/canberra_hero_image.jpg'); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks,But if i want an image in that area?

Comment: Look at my answer I edited it. Don't forget to mark the correct answer when you solve the problem.
body {
background:url('http://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/canberra_hero_image.jpg'); 
}

Comment: But the area of  header and footer will cut it from top and bottom?

Comment: Thats because you are placing image in body. Which wraps around all the elements. You will need to add extra element after header and before footer that will be your content container. But that is currently part of a different problem.

Comment: by the "element" you mean a div with some empty space?

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/xqxrmm96/1/

html-

```
<html>
 <body>
  <header></header>
  <section></section>
  <footer></footer>
 </body>
</html>
```

css-

```
header {
    height: 30px;
    background-color: #e0e0e0;
}
section {
    height: 60px;
    background-color: #efefef;
}
footer {
    height: 30px;
    background-color: #e1e1e1;
}
```

you can do it something like this

Comment: Managed that, but under the css section part eg. section{ position:absolute;height:60px;background-color:#000; }  ,the "position" makes it go wrong.

Comment: and what html structure you want?

Comment: header || section || Footer